# FTP Server is forcing connection via SSL

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I have a Windows server that is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1.

We have a FTP site that has been running for years, and now suddenly is not working.  The site is set up to allow SSL connections, but it doesn't require them.

Using FileZilla, a user tries to connect, they will get the following.

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.mycompany.com
Status: Connecting to 199.255.220.105:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER myftpuser
Response:   331 Password required for myftpuser.
Command:    PASS *********
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Things all look good until it tried to list the directory content, and then I get the error noted above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix FileZilla's response: "550 The supplied message is incomplete. The signature was not verified."?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685967/how-to-fix-filezillas-response-550-the-supplied-message-is-incomplete-the-si). In short: It's a bug in IIS and Microsoft provides a hotfix.

Comment: The duplicate issue that you are referring to wasn't fixed by the HotFix.  The user simply used a different client.  I am having the issue with both FTP clients, so it's not the same issue.  In addition, I have a secondary symptom from the underlying issue that the other question does not address.

Comment: @JeffReddy That's not correct conclusion. Without the hotfix, WinSCP won't work either. That's why the problem is [documented on WinSCP site](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_supplied_message_incomplete), right? So please try the suggestion and complain, only after it does not work.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that there isn't an accepted solution on that question.  I have my infrastructure team working on applying the hotfix.

Comment: The  problem encountered had nothing to do with a hotfix.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

This issue is due to the fact that my server is shielded from the Internet with NAT (Network Address Translation).  The FileZilla client receives a response with the internal IP of the server for passive mode and compares it with the known public address. Because it is not the same address it will terminate, i.e. disconnect from the server. Connection aborted!

So, this isn't an error, but rather by design. You will simply need to make sure you connect via SSL or, in IIS, set up FTP Firewall Support.  Once I set the external IP Address of the Firewall, I could again connect without SSL.